# Unable to locate package msodbcsql

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I'm trying to install mssql driver on Ubuntu 16.04 using this [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).
When I get into the step :

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql
```

I got an error : Unable to locate package msodbcsql
What step did I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems, because, according to that url, right command for Ubuntu is:

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

**full script for 16.04:**

```
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version


#Ubuntu 16.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list


exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

---

**Update (13 Apr 18)**

Consider to check that Microsoft repository properly registered by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

As a result you should see a line similar to a *"Get:30 http packages.microsoft.com/ .."*

My vm example:

```
Get:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,208 B]
Get:30 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial/main amd64 Packages [31.7 kB]
Fetched 12.9 MB in 5s (2,265 kB/s)
```

Comment: The most important that sudo apt-get update shows this line: 

Get:30 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial/main amd64 Packages [31.7 kB]

It means that you properly registered Microsoft repository at: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list.

Comment: After running your script, my apt-get update is not working (-1)

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error on Debian GNU/Linux 9.

It turn out to be the failure in `apt-get update`

```
# apt-get update
....
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod/dists/stretch/InRelease
```

According to the error log, I ran `apt-get install apt-transport-https` and  `apt-get update` again.

Then I can do the `ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17` successfully

> Note: I was in root, if you're not, add sudo, try it. :)

Answer (score 2):

After searching, I have found the requested package is located on Microsoft Ubuntu 18.04 repository.
To install the package We have to add the repository first and then we have to run following commands.

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic 
main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install msodbcsql17
```

Above command will setup msodbcsql17.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

**Error Message**: *Unable to locate package msodbcsql17*

**Solution**: Update the Ubuntu release version to the current latest!

```
      - curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
      - curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
      - apt update -y
      - apt install msodbcsql17 -y
      - apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y
```

basically what worked for me was upgrading from `/ubuntu/16.04` to `/ubuntu/20.04`

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error while using the `python:3.10-slim` docker image whose base image is the Debian 12. In this case, you need to install two  dependencies before installing the `msodbcsql18` package:

```bash
apt install -y curl unixodbc odbcinst
```

Find the suitable MSODBC driver package under the [Download for Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#download-for-linux-and-macos) documentation. Get the package URL and download it via `curl` command, in my case:

```bash
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/12/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql18/msodbcsql18_18.3.2.1-1_amd64.deb -o msodbcsql18.deb
```

Next, install the package using the `dpkg` package manager:

```bash
ACCEPT_EULA=Y dpkg --install msodbcsql18.deb
```

> Note: Do not forget to accept the license agreement.